# Points contained in envelopes that cross date-line - java

Tags: geometry, java, esri-geometry-api-java

I'm using the ESRI Geometry Java API https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java

I want to construct an envelope and see if it contains certain points. It's possible the envelope crosses the International date line.

Here is some sample code I've tried:

```
    double lon = Double.parseDouble("179.99");
    double lat = Double.parseDouble("0");
    Point pt = new Point(lon, lat);

    double minlon = Double.parseDouble("170");
    double minlat = Double.parseDouble("-20");

    double maxlon = Double.parseDouble("-170");
    double maxlat = Double.parseDouble("20");

    Envelope ev = new Envelope(minlon, minlat, maxlon, maxlat);

    SpatialReference sr = SpatialReference.create(4326); // decimal degrees

    boolean test = GeometryEngine.contains(ev, pt, sr);

    System.out.println(GeometryEngine.geometryToJson(sr, ev));
    assertTrue("envelope containts point true", test);
```

The test fails, and if I check the print statement I get a json that has swapped my x-coordinates

```
{"xmin":-170,"ymin":-20,"xmax":170,"ymax":20,"spatialReference":{"wkid":4326}}
```

Is there a different/better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The Esri Geometry API for Java documentation states that it implements geometry for a plane, so will not take the Date Line into account:

[In geometry-api-java, the geometry is planar with the exception of `GeometryEngine.geodesicDistanceOnWGS84`. The X/Y values are considered on an infinite plane, and all operations are executed based on that assumption.](https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java/wiki)

[Disclosure: I am a collaborator on Esri GIS-Tools-for-Hadoop.]